# Iterating through a HashMap until the first value is found?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, hashmap, compare

I have a HashMap that I have used to store an integer id and an String value.

I wanted to be able to remove things from the HashMap based off of a user input String. The way I have been doing that is as followed:

```
        public void pickingVehicleUp() {

        System.out.println("Please enter number plate: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String PLATE = input.nextLine();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iter = zone_1.entrySet().iterator();

        Map.Entry<Integer, String> Empty1 = iter.next();
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> Empty2 = iter.next();
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> Empty3 = iter.next();
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> Empty4 = iter.next();
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> Empty5 = iter.next();

        zone_1.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> (PLATE.equals(entry.getValue())));

        if (Empty1.getValue().equals(PLATE)) {
            Integer key = Empty1.getKey();
            zone_1.put(key, "Empty");
        } else if (Empty2.getValue().equals(PLATE)) {
            Integer key = Empty2.getKey();
            zone_1.put(key, "Empty");
        } else if (Empty3.getValue().equals(PLATE)) {
            Integer key = Empty3.getKey();
            zone_1.put(key, "Empty");
        } else if (Empty4.getValue().equals(PLATE)) {
            Integer key = Empty4.getKey();
            zone_1.put(key, "Empty");
        } else if (Empty5.getValue().equals(PLATE)) {
            Integer key = Empty5.getKey();
            zone_1.put(key, "Empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("That number plate doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
```

While this code works fine, I think that it is very untidy and there are probably much more efficient ways to do it and i'd like to find one of those ways as I need to do this same method for 5 different HashMaps.

Comment: What is this map containing (as keys and as value. Not just the type: their meaning). What are you trying to achieve? The whole design looks really wrong, but since we don't know what you're trying to design, it's hard to help.

Comment: I was doing a parking structure, I used an ArrayList to store the vehicles and I divided it into Zones using a HashMap for each Zone. The Key is the parking space ID, and the plate represents which Vehicle is in the space. Then when the user enters the plate, it removes it and then  puts "Empty" in it's place. I also have another Method that puts the vehicles in "Empty" places. I'm sure there are better and more logical ways of doing it, this is just what I thought of first :l

Comment: If your goal is to find the space ID form a plate, then the key of the map should be the plate, and the value the space ID, not vice-versa. If you really want or need to keep it that way, then *loop* over the entries to find the one which has the plate as values. Your code repeats the same thing 5 times, and only works if your parking has only 5 spaces.

Comment: yeah, I wanted to loop it like that, i'm just not sure how to do it is the thing, also what would I get from changing it so that plate was the key? Would it just be easier to iterate through it and fine the key than it is to find the value?

Comment: You don't need to iterate if you have the key of a map. All you need to do is to call get(key) on the map to get the value. That's the principle of a map. You already know how to get an iterator on the entrySet of the map. So use a loop to iterate over it instead of calling next() 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this would help you

```
String PLATE = "PLATE";

    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, "DOOR");
    map.put(2, "DOG");
    map.put(3, "PLATE");
    map.put(4, "SNOW");

    System.out.println("Before check - " + map);

    if (map.containsValue(PLATE)) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> item:map.entrySet()) {
            if (item.getValue().equals(PLATE)) {
                map.remove(item.getKey());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("After check - " + map);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier if you reversed the Map as JB Nizet suggests in the comments.  Intuitively, if you are looking for Plate and where it is located, it makes more sense for your Map to store parking space ID as a function of Plate number.  Then it makes your task trivial:

```
String PLATE = "PLATE1";
Map<String, Integer> plateToParkingSpaceID = new HashMap<>();

plateToParkingSpaceID.put("PLATE1", 1);
plateToParkingSpaceID.put("PLATE2", 2);
plateToParkingSpaceID.put("PLATE3", 3);
plateToParkingSpaceID.put("PLATE4", 4);

if (plateToParkingSpaceID.containsKey(PLATE)) {
    plateToParkingSpaceID.remove(PLATE);
} else {
    System.out.println("That number plate doesn't exist!");
}
```

However, if you keep you current design of mapping the parking space to the license place, we can do the following:

```
String PLATE = "PLATE1";
Optional<Integer> parkingSpaceId = zone1.entrySet().stream()  // stream all of the entries in the zone1 Map
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals())                       // filter out all that don't have the correct plate
    .findFirst()                                              // there should be 0 or 1 of these, so we can stop as soon as we find the first one

if (parkingSpaceId.isPresent()) {
    zone1.remove(parkingSpaceId.get());  // remove that space from the map
} else {
    System.out.println("That number plate doesn't exist!");
}
```